# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Country.Name'. even when I don't use ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I my ASP.NET MVC 4 application I have a contact form with countries drop-down menu. For that menu I use Html.DropDownListFor helper method. But if country is not selected I'm getting exception: **"There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Country.Name'."** This is my controller:

```
ContactViewModel contactViewModel = new ContactViewModel();
contactViewModel.Countries = DbUnitOfWork.CountriesRepository.GetAll()
    .Select(c => c.Name)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = c.ToString(),
        Text = c.ToString()
    });
```

This is in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country.Name,
    Model.Countries,
    Resources.SelectCountry,
    dropdown)
```

As you can see I'm not using ViewData. How to prevent this exception? I have in my model attribute [Required] but no error message is showing.

**Update**

This is the fields for country in my view model:

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "CountryErrorMessage")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resource), Name = "Country")]
    public CountryModel Country { get; set; }
```

And this is in the view

```
   @model MyApp.ViewModels.ContactViewModel
```

Comment: Where's the code for your view model? That's what it's complaining about I believe. Also, in your view, what's the `@model` set to at the top of the view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've typically seen this when the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is not instantiated.

In your ViewModel, try adding a **constructor** like this:

```
public ContactViewModel()
{
    Countries = new List<SelectListItem>();
}
```

Comment: It works! Now I'm not getting the exception if country is not selected but also I'm not getting the error message.